# How to write display Information to MVC ViewModel in mvc4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

My first question on here,

In my domain I have classes called

Student:

```
public class Student:Person
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

Project:

```
public class Project
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProjectID { get; set; }
    public int ProjectNO { get; set; }
    public string Module { get; set; }
    public string  ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
    public bool IsGroupProject { get; set; }
    public decimal Budget { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Student> Student { get; set; }
    public virtual Supervisor Supervisor { get; set; }
}
```

Component:

```
public class Component
{

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ComponentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StockCode { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Order:

```
public class Order
{


    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsCollected { get; set; }
    public DateTime CollectionDate { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Component> Components { get; set; }

    public void CheckBudget()
    {

    }

}
```

I have a view model called requestcomponent

```
public class RequestComponent
{


    [Key]
    public int RequestID { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
    public Component Component { get; set; }
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying do two things:

1) Display the data from the Student, Project, Component and orders Model in the view.
2) Write data by using forms to Student, Project, Component and orders Model in the view.

Please can you guide me.

Thanks for you help in advance.

Comment: What exactly you want to display? what is the finalized view

Comment: What do you have in your view so far, or are you just not sure how to start?

Comment: Your view model is just a combination of domain models while it should be a combination of other view models. So `Student` should have a view model (i.e. `StudentModel`). The same counts for the other properties. Your solution doesn't tackle the problem completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view model for the view and prepare it in the controller.
I am not sure what is the structure of the information you want to present.

Assuming here you want to display `Order Information`

For this, create a `OrderViewModel` and put the view specific properties to it. It is not necessary to include all other properties from `Order`

```
public class OrderViewModel
{
    public int OrderID { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsCollected { get; set; }
    public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
    //add any view specific properties, if needed like IsEditable
}
```

In a Order controller

```
public ActionResult FindOrder(int id)
{

    Order order=DBContext.Orders.FindById(id); // get it from repository

    OrderViewModel viewModel=new OrderViewModel();
    viewModel.Id=order.Id; // etc, etc
    //Do this mapping with AutoMapper, recommended

    return View(viewModel);
}
```

In Views/Order/FindOrder.cshtml

```
@model OrderViewModel 

<div id="order-details">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveOrder", "Order", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form-orderInfo"}))
    {

     <label>Name</label>
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name, new { @id = "order-name" })
     <!-- etc -->

    }
</div>


public ActionResult SaveOrder(OrderViewModel model)
{
 Order order= prepare this from OrderViewModel object. Use AutoMapper
}
```

Read about [`AutoMapper Article`](http://bengtbe.com/blog/2009/04/14/using-automapper-to-map-view-models-in-asp-net-mvc/)